# Convert a char* to a SEXP

Tags: r, rcpp

I need to convert a `const char*` of known length into a `Rcpp::RawVector`to be returned into R.

`Rcpp::wrap` works for many types but doesn't seem to work for `char *`.

Comment: The OP did @KonstantinAzizov. They were trying to use something like `Rcpp::wrap(var)` where `var` was a `const char *` and there's no automatic handler for this in Rcpp.

Comment: The question is whether the one-to-one mapping is desired, or whether the `const char *` is to be serialized? In that case package [RApiSerialize](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/RApiSerialize/index.html) (which is used by eg [RcppRedis](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppRedis/index.html)) can help.

Comment: In my case I want to pass serialized data from R to another app and vice versa

Comment: You may find [RcppRedis](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppRedis/index.html) helpful then as it serializes R objects to/from Redis.  You may as well talk directly to another box.  The implementations there are meant to be efficient -- hence the access to the aforementioned [RApiSerialize](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/RApiSerialize/index.html).

Answer (score 8):

```
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)

ƒ <- rcpp(body='
const char* text = "this is some text";
Rcpp::RawVector rv(strlen(text));
for(unsigned int i=0; i<strlen(text); i++) { rv[i] = text[i]; }
return(rv);
')

ƒ()
##  [1] 74 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 73 6f 6d 65 20 74 65 78 74

rawToChar(ƒ())
## [1] "this is some text"
```

**UPDATE**

[`@nrussell`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1869097/nrussell)'s [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39250448/convert-a-char-to-a-sexp/39250933?noredirect=1#comment65847996_39250933) is way better:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <cstring>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::RawVector to_raw(const char* str) {
    Rcpp::RawVector res(str, str + std::strlen(str));
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked out for me with this solution! 
I was wondering if there was a more concise way with rcpp

Comment: @Marc Faddoul The `Vector` constructor [accepts begin and end iterators](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/edbe275162037a98b1c517baae26f016) which may be *slightly* more concise.

Comment: you should def add that as an answer @nrussell. it's ++gd better than mine and I shld have remembered that given that I just used that same construct quite a bit in an internal work pkg (sigh).

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment, but I wouldn't have even bothered looking into it if I hadn't seen your answer in the first place. Please feel free to add it to your solution.

Comment: Thank you @nrussell, that's what I was looking for! Cheers for the update hrbmstr